# Vue ElementUI Webpack externals using CDN

Tags: webpack, vue.js, element-ui, webpack-externals

Try to set up project with Vue and ElementUI using webpack4. I want to pull both Vue and ElementUI from CDN so I have below webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: ["./app.js"],
  externals: {
    vue: "Vue",
    "element-ui": "ElementUI"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /.ttf$|.woff$/,
        use: [{ loader: "url-loader", options: { limit: 10000 } }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    [v-cloak] {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div v-cloak id="root">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.runtime.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/2.3.4/index.js"></script>
  <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

my app.js has has root Vue instance

```
import Vue from "vue";
import ElementUI from "element-ui";
import Counter from "./Counter.vue";

Vue.use(ElementUI);

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  render: h => h(Counter)
});
```

Counter component is below

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    incement() {
      this.counter++;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p><span>Count: </span>{{counter}}</p>
    <el-button @click="incement">Incement</el-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

When i open the app in the browser I get below error

external_"ElementUI":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ElementUI is not defined
at this line in webpack generated js file module.exports = ElementUI;

is there something I am missing in this? Vue external works without any issues only having problems with the element UI

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? If yes, please post answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your webpack configuration `"element-ui": "ElementUI"` tells webpack that "element-ui" is available as a global variable `ElementUI`.

Webpack creates the code snippet `module.exports = ElementUI;` so that whenever you import (or require w/e) "element-ui", it will return this global variable.

Now it seems that `ElementUI` does not exist in the global scope hence the ReferenceError.
The script ...element-ui/2.3.4/index.js adds a global variable `Element` so try to change your webpack configuration with `"element-ui": "Element"`

Comment: Thanks for this. You've really added something valuable to Stackoverflow.

One addition to your answer; `ElementUI` also needs to become `ELEMENT` everywhere it appears in app.js.

@PKool — you should mark this as the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks I have moved on from this. But it looks like something that will work.